# CountIFS() Always Returning a 0

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, countif

I am using this formula in Excel VBA to insert the `CountIFS()` formula, however the count returned is always 0?

This is the VBA syntax I am using: (I formatted it to add a space after the comma to look better in this window, in my VBA it is all one line)

```
With ws
.Range("C2:C" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Students!C[-2],RC[-2],
                              Students!C,""<>James"",
                              Students!C,""<>Joanne"",
                              Students!C,""<>Lisa"",
                              Students!C,""<>Marin"",
                              Students!C,""<>Alfie"",
                              Students!C,""<>Parent Volunteer"",
                              Students!C[6],""'Current"")                             
End with
```

Which if I look at the formula after the VBA inputs it into the cell it eqates to this:

```
=COUNTIFS([Students.xlsx]Names!A:A,A2,
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>James",
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>Joanne",
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>Lisa",
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>Marin",
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>Alfie",
[Students.xlsx]Names!C:C,"<>Parent Volunteer",
[Students.xlsx]Names!I:I,"Current")
```

Which that looks like the correct syntax.  What do I need to change in this syntax in order to have it provide accurate counts?

Comment: Looks and tests correct on a single worksheet. Check for leading/trailing spaces, non-breaking spaces or unprintable characters in Names' columns A and I.

Comment: There are no leading/trailing spaces.  What would be considered an unprintable character?

Comment: Try filtering column A = A2, column I = "Current" and verify that there is at least 1 name in column C that isn't an excluded name.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - yes, I just verified that condition is met.  Meaning >= 1 name is returned when fitlered.

Comment: There are many but a common one would be a CHAR(10) or CHAR(13) left over from a copy and paste off a web page. The `=LEN(A2)` will show an extra character in length; **Current** should be 7 characters long.

Comment: @Jeeped - that was it, there was CHAR(13) in the cells!