# VBA CountIFS With Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I have a VBA procedure that scans a worksheet and produces counts where cell C is not equal to certain colors, but column I is set to one value.  This is the procedure:

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,""<>Red"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Blue"",Sheet1!C,""<>Green"",Sheet1!C,""<>Black"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Purple"",Sheet1!C,""<>White"",
Sheet1!C[6],""Temp"")"
```

Conditions have changed and I need to add in another criteria for count condition so I thought it would be a quick fix of adding in a comma and the criteria to the end like this

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,""<>Red"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Blue"",Sheet1!C,""<>Green"",Sheet1!C,""<>Black"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Purple"",Sheet1!C,""<>White"",
Sheet1!C[6],""Temp"",Sheet1!C[6],""Perm"")"
```

However - now this always returns 0.  What is the correct way to add in a secondary condition in VBA to a CountIFS()

**EDIT**
That second parameter I want to add, should be an "OR" condition as well, so Sheet1!C[6] = Temp OR Perm

**EDIT 2**
I tried to edit my syntax like this

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,""<>Red"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Blue"",Sheet1!C,""<>Green"",Sheet1!C,""<>Black"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Purple"",Sheet1!C,""<>White"",
Sheet1!C[6],""Temp"")"
+
"COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,""<>Red"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Blue"",Sheet1!C,""<>Green"",Sheet1!C,""<>Black"",
Sheet1!C,""<>Purple"",Sheet1!C,""<>White"",
Sheet1!C[6],""Perm"")"
```

but this gives me an error of

> application defiend or object defined error

Comment: Inside the `COUNTIFS` everything is an AND... for the OR just sum your `COUNTIFS` like `=COUNTIFS(...Temp...)+COUNTIFS(...Perm...)`. Unlike your case keep in mind: if multiple parts of the OR can be true you need to subtract that cases where this happens or it will be counted multiple times.

Comment: @DirkReichel - see my edit.  I must just be off with the syntax.  I tried to add a + in there and am getting an error....And thanks for the words of advice.  There is only the possibility for ONE answer to be in the cell, I just need to check for both.

Comment: Your question is strikingly similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880532/countifs-always-returning-a-0. Are you guys working on the same project perhaps? Anyway - the answer to other question was that it was just a typo.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - unfortunately in my instance there is no typo.  Well there couldbe in the syntax, I just don't see it.  No not the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim f
f = "=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,'<>Red'," & _
    "Sheet1!C,'<>Blue',Sheet1!C,'<>Green',Sheet1!C,'<>Black'," & _
    "Sheet1!C,'<>Purple',Sheet1!C,'<>White'," & _
    "Sheet1!C[6],'Temp') + COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C[-2],RC[-2],Sheet1!C,'<>Red'," & _
    "Sheet1!C,'<>Blue',Sheet1!C,'<>Green',Sheet1!C,'<>Black'," & _
    "Sheet1!C,'<>Purple',Sheet1!C,'<>White',Sheet1!C[6],'Perm')"


FormulaR1C1 = Replace(f, "'", """")
```